# PYTHON: Getting an error running keras model when trying to convert df to np.array and run model.predict

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

**Introduction**: 
My goal or what i want to achieve is that given certain numbers always 3, get a prediction, maybe taking the date into consideration, haven't got that far because i was trying to get this working first and then analyze the date too...

**Error**: 
When trying to convert df into an np array and then call model.predict:
Gettin an exception here because this was supposed to be: 
**Working**: scaled_predicted_output1 = model.predict(np.array([scaled_to_predict])) 
**Error**: scaled_predicted_output1 = model.predict(df.to_numpy([scaled_to_predict])) 
**Error Image**:
[https://i.ibb.co/0V3Crgq/Python-Error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qhaA.png)

**Full Code**:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Bidirectional, Dropout

batch_size = 100

#Real CSV file consists of an data like 05-16-2022,22,33,98
df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv', header=None)
df = df.iloc[:,[1,2,3]]

scaler = StandardScaler().fit(df.values)
transformed_dataset = scaler.transform(df.values)
transformed_df = pd.DataFrame(data=transformed_dataset,index = df.index)

number_of_rows = df.values.shape[0]
window_lenght = 10
number_of_features = df.values.shape[1]

train = np.empty([number_of_rows-window_lenght,window_lenght,number_of_features], dtype=float)
label = np.empty([number_of_rows-window_lenght,number_of_features], dtype=float)

window_lenght = 10

for i in range(0,number_of_rows-window_lenght):
    train[i]=transformed_df.iloc[i:i+window_lenght, 0: number_of_features]
    label[i]=transformed_df.iloc[i+window_lenght: i+window_lenght+1, 0:number_of_features]


model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(240,input_shape=(window_lenght,number_of_features),return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(240,input_shape=(window_lenght,number_of_features),return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(240,input_shape=(window_lenght,number_of_features),return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(240,input_shape=(window_lenght,number_of_features),return_sequences=False)))

model.add(Dense(59))
model.add(Dense(number_of_features))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train,label,batch_size=100,epochs=30)

#Real CSV file consists of an data like 05-16-2022,22,33,98
df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv', header=None)
df = df.iloc[:,[1,2,3]]

to_predict = df.to_numpy()
scaled_to_predict = scaler.transform(to_predict)

#Gettin an exception here because this was supposed to be: scaled_predicted_output1 = model.predict(np.array([scaled_to_predict]))
scaled_predicted_output1 = model.predict(df.to_numpy([scaled_to_predict]))
print(scaler.inverse_tranform(scaled_predicted_output1).astype(int)[0])
```

Comment: You need to include the error message

Comment: Done added error as screenshot.